# NONMEM 7.2 reads Matlab codes while processing structures printed by Matlab to csv

Tags: matlab, csv, structure

I need somebody familiar with both NONMEM 7.2 and Matlab R2013a to answer my question. I used the code published here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34889-struct2csv to make a datafile (a .csv file) for simulations in NONMEM. When NONMEM tries reading the .csv file, it ends up reading code of the file in Matlab. Why is this happening and what is the solution to this?

Additionally, if somebody has an alternative technique of writing structures to a .csv file, I would appreciate it. I'm sorry I cannot post the code because this is related to a research project in progress.

Regards,

Kumpal

Comment: Have you taken the *.csv file you write out and looked at it in Excel or similar to make sure it's of the format you expect? There's really very little advice that can be offered if we don't know what your data structure looks like to start with.

Comment: The .csv file looks exactly like how I want it to, with headers on top and numbers below with exactly the same number of rows and columns that I expect.

Comment: Then it's something in how you're running NONMEM (although I can't see any reason why it would do anything with "code of the file in Matlab").  Is your .csv file in the working directory with the .ctl file?

Comment: Yes it is. If this can't be troubleshooted, I'm willing to have another way of converting structures to csv than the one in the link I posted. Maybe that works out.